# React: How do I get non-choppy getUserMedia video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I use a `<video>` tag with getUserMedia in react, the result is super choppy. See this fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nLmdoaua/

However, when I use getUserMedia outside of React, it performs just fine.

How do I get performant video in React?

Answer (score 1):

I think this lib can solve your problem, I did a quick test and I got the same issue as your. Have a look a it [here](https://react.rocks/example/react-webcam), sorry

Comment: Thanks! Examining the code I found the difference was the `autoPlay` attribute :)